# How to: android app that uploads/downloads to hosting?

Tags: android, hosting

I am playing with the idea of making an app that allows you to upload text and images/videos to a server and also download the content from there (something like a forum kind of thing, but in a smaller scale). I have purchased some hosting online (for a webpage I'm working on) and wondered if I could use this.There is some FTP info in there as well as some Database info.

Is there some tutorial/guide/information out there that can help me learn how to do this? I've spent a while googling around and not sure what I should be googling exactly. I have some experience making apps, but never done any "communication" stuff. Anyone that can point me in the right direction would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went to [security exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/82353/android-app-using-ftp) and found out that FTP isn't that safe. Someone suggested HTTP upload instead.

I found a couple of tutorials (haven't tested them yet) that seem to do what I want:

http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/